# Late 80s/early 90s young adult sci-fi book about teenage girl living on the moon after Earth's invasion by aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, soft-sci-fi, alien-invasion

The book is about a teenage girl who lives on the Moon after aliens take over the Earth. I think there was a picture of a blonde girl sitting and the moon in the background on the cover. It was one of my favourite and I'd like to share it with my kids.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76277/girl-living-on-the-moon-flying-trip-to-earth?

Comment: The aliens taking over the Earth sounds like John Varley's "Eight Worlds" setting. Going through his bibliography might be a good place to start.

Comment: About the cover picture.  If the artist painted the girl sitting on the Moon with the moon in the sky behind her that would have been a mistake.  Or did the artist paint the girl sitting on the moon with a moonscape behind her?  Or did the artist paint the girl sitting on Earth before the alien invasion with the Moon in the sky behind her?  Or were the girl and the Moon supposed to be two different picture elements and not part of the same scene?

Comment: I second the recommendation to check out John Varley’s Eight World’s series.

Comment: I don't know that I'd class any of Varley's stories in that setting as "young adult" -- though I gather the standards for that genre have changed a good bit since I was in its target group (forty years?!).  There were a few with teen protagonists, however.

Answer (score -2):

*This Place Has No Atmosphere* (1986) by Paula Danziger.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/131847.This_Place_Has_No_Atmosphere):

> In the year 2057 people live in malls, take classes in ESP, and get detention from robots. Fifteen-year-old Aurora loves everything about her life. She’s part of the coolest group of kids at school and has just started dating the best-looking guy in her grade. Then her parents make the announce­ment that she’s sure will ruin her life—the family’s moving to the moon! What with water rationing, no privacy, and freeze-dried ham­burgers, how will Aurora ever feel like she’s home again?

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if you could indicate why this is a match for the question.

Comment: This definitely doesn't sound like the Earth has been taken over by aliens.  Most people _live_ on Earth and there are only 750 people in the Moon colony.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

I remember this book. I think the person asking, may have mis-remembered the alien part. But the rest sounds right.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please don't post answers that are duplicates of existing answers.  This answer also doesn't provide any reasons why this matches the question; you should read [answer] and take the [tour].